Pipenv update on private gitlab package
We are making some packages internally so we don't have to copy paste all code around. We deployed it to gitlab's package registry. Adding the gitlab index to our pipfile worked fine for installing using pipenv install <our-package> --index=<our-index>
[[source]]
url = "https://${CI_DEPLOY_USER}:${CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}@<our-git-adress>/api/v4/projects/<package-project-number>/packages/pypi/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "<our-index>"

Now we have made some updates to the package. We want to update the package in some other project using
pipenv update <package> --index=<our-index>
in our other projects.
(We used the same setup as mentioned above with the pipfile, which works for installing.)
We get this error:

CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Cannot
install  because these package versions have
conflicting dependencies.

So I looked into the dependencies. The package i'm using has no dependecies. All other packages don't have a dependency on this package. Why would I have a conflict in the dependencies?
Also, when i uninstall the package using
pipenv uninstall <our-package> --index=<our-index>

I get another error:
Error running command:  $ Path/To/Virtual/Env/Scripts/python.exe Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\__pip-runner__.py uninstall <our-package> -y
STDERR:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\__pip-runner__.py", line 50, in <module>
    runpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 226, in run_module
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\pip\__main__.py", line 28, in <module>
    spec.loader.exec_module(pipenv)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pipenv.cli import cli  # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .command import cli  # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pipenv import environments
  File "Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\environments.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pipenv.utils.fileutils import normalize_drive
  File "Path\To\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import logging
  File "Path\To\Virtual\Env\lib\site-packages\logging\__init__.py", line 618
    raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It does remove the package from my pipfile but not from my pipfile.lock. After doing this, installing works again and I get the newest version. (So somehow, removing the package from the pipfile makes it work again or something)
If an older version is installed and we reinstall it using a version specifier. So, lets say the package is at version 0.1.1 and a newer version 0.1.5 is available and I run (without uninstalling!):
pipenv install <our-package>==0.1.5 --index=<our-index>

It runs fine.
So why would the update give the error? And also, why do I get an error when uninstalling?
I'm using:

python 3.12.2,
pip 24.0 and
pipenv 2023.12.1

(the newest versions as of writing this)

logging should be part of the standard library, but for some reason your environment contains a third-party logging package (hence \site-packages\logging\__init__.py) that contains code that only works in Python 2.x (hence the code shown in the stack trace and the corresponding error). Try uninstalling that first.

If it was this one, that hasn't been updated since 2013, and it was originally a proof of concept by the person who added the standard library module... to Python 2.3... which was released in 2003.

Although, the standard library logging should get found before the site-packages one, with sys.path configured normally. It's worth looking into that, at least as far as making sure that your environment does have the standard library logging. If not, something else is seriously broken and requires more debugging detail.

As for "Cannot install because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.", debugging that would require seeing which packages and versions are cited in the error message.

What result do you get from Path/To/Virtual/Env/Scripts/python.exe -c "import logging; print(logging.__file__)"? How about Path/To/Virtual/Env/Scripts/python.exe -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"?
